# Javascript slider class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I'm doing something wrong but can't find what? will be grateful if someone can help me. this JavaScript code works perfectly fine when I check it on my website but once I host it online it does not

```
$(".slider").click(function(){

    if ($('.sliding_navigation').hasClass('trial')){
        $('.sliding_navigation').removeClass('trial');
        alert('works');

    } 
    else 
    {
        $('.sliding_navigation').addClass('trial');
        alert('even this works');
    }
});
```

problem is when i click the slider class it removes the trial class but after that it automatically proceeds to execute the else statement and adds the class creating no effect at all I've been running in circles with this and will be grateful for any help; 
this is the html code i'm targeting

```
<div class="complete_nav">

<header class="slider">MENU</header>

<header class="sliding_navigation trial">
    <nav >

        <ul>
            <a href="#" ><li class="select"><b>HOME</b></li></a>
          <a href="aboutme.html"><li><b>ABOUT ME</b></li></a>
          <a href="from_my_pen.html"><li><b>FROM MY PEN</b></li></a>
          <a href="books.html"><li><b>BOOKS</b></li></a>
          <a href="reviews_and_press.html"><li><b>REVIEWS AND PRESS</b></li></a>
          <a href="contact_me.html"><li><b>CONTACT ME</b></li></a>              
        </ul>

    </nav>
</header>

</div>
```

trial class has display set to none.

Comment: maybe add a return true; and return false; to the end of your if statements

Comment: I've put that code in a snippet here, and it doesn't do what you say - is this the **exact** code, or perhaps you've removed something vital to the problem - here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx36p9xn/) with your code (excluding the annoying alerts - use the console for debugging)

Comment: ^Same as me, there must be something else as well maybe?

Comment: Looks like the event is handled twice. Did you maybe include a minified and a non-minified version on the page?

Comment: Looks like click event is attached twice.. remove the earlier click event using .off('click')...try this $(".slider").off('click').click(function(){....}

Comment: yup i did not link properly... sorry for asking stupid questions

Answer (score 3):

You can replace all that javascript with this :

```
$(".slider").click(function(){
    $('.sliding_navigation').toggleClass('trial');
});
```

`$.toggleClass()` alone, checks whether an element has the certain class, and removes it if it does, or adds it if it doesn't.
And this works for me pretty well, just add :

```
.trial {
    display:none;
}
```

See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/LnpLzykp/
Don't forget to add this to your code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT :** Perhaps you have more of those in your code, in this case, use this instead :

```
$(".slider").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.sliding_navigation').toggleClass('trial');
});
```

This way you're telling javascript to toggle the class trial only for the `.sliding-navigation` that is directly below the `.slider`.
Check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/LnpLzykp/1/
I'm using four menus to illustrate the new code.

Comment: same thinking here

Comment: Yes, can't see what's wrong, unless he's not linking jquery in the right way

Answer (score 0):

it's official i'm a fool.... i had put the scripts twice so like some people pointed out it was clicking twice.. sorry for wasting your time and thanks a lot